# Extracting dictionary values into .txt files

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I am looking to create .txt files from a dictionary, extracting text into new lines of each txt file - dictionary structure looks like:

```
{'id': 0,
 'text': 'Mtendere Village was inspired by the vision'}
```

I am using this code:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm  #loading bar

text_data = []
file_count = 0

for sample in tqdm(new_dict):
    # remove newline characters from each sample as we need to use exclusively as seperators
    sample = sample['text'].replace('\n', '\s')
    text_data.append(sample)
    if len(text_data) == 5_000:
        # once we hit the 5K mark, save to file
        with open('file_path\oscar_data\oscar_%s.txt' %file_count, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            fp.write('\n'.join(text_data)) 
        text_data = []
        file_count += 1
```

However this gives me an error;

```
---> 12     sample = sample['text'].replace('\n', '\s') 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Although I understand what the error is telling me, I'm not sure how to correct it...

Comment: yes because you need to access the `text` key of the `sample` dictionary instead of trying to access it directly!

Comment: what is `new_dict` ?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Unless the number of dictionary entries is an exact multiple of 5,000 you'll lose data because you don't account for that scenario when the *for* loop terminates. '\s' is not a valid escape sequence. The backslashes in your file path will work in this case as directory separators on Windows but **only** because '\o' is not an escape sequence. Research raw strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to pass a list of dictionaries to the loop, but actually passed a dictionary.

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm  #loading bar

new_dict = [
    {
        'id': 0,
        'text': 'Mtendere Village was inspired by the vision'
    }
]

text_data = []
file_count = 0

for sample in tqdm(new_dict):
    # remove newline characters from each sample as we need to use exclusively as seperators
    sample = sample['text'].replace('\n', '\s')
    text_data.append(sample)
    if len(text_data) == 5000:
        # Once we hit the 5K mark, save it to file
        with open('file_path\oscar_data\oscar_%s.txt' %file_count, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            fp.write('\n'.join(text_data)) 
        
        text_data = []
        file_count += 1
```

I have updated `new_dict` to a list of dictionaries and it fixed the issue.